# Changing mongoid embeds_many association name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Using Rails 3.2, and Mongoid 2.4. I have a legacy model, Organization, that embeds_many organization_members. It looks something like this:

```
class Organization
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :organization_members
end

class OrganizationMembers
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :organization
end
```

What I'd like to do is change the method I use to access members from **organization.organization_members** to just **organization.members**. Here's what I've done:

```
class Organization
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :members, class_name:"OrganizationMember"
end

class OrganizationMembers
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :organization
end
```

However, now organization.members returns an empty array and organization.organization_members returns the previous documents, even though it church_members isn't defined.

How do I persuade Mongoid to use the previous embedded collection name and access it through the new method call (Organization#members not Organization#organization_members)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an option to [`embeds_many`](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_many), called `store_as`.

```
class Organization
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :members, 
              class_name:"OrganizationMember", 
              store_as: 'organization_members'
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, and it responds with an Invalid Option error. Apparently, store_as is only relevant since Mongoid 3 (http://www.rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Relations/Metadata:store_as). Do you know of a 2.4 equivalent for this?

Comment: @Glenn: If I were stuck with 2.4, I'd rename the old field in the database.

Comment: I guess its time to upgrade. I started looking at monkey patching for my use case, and it just seemed to make more sense to bite the bullet and get on Mongoid 3. Thanks for your input. Appreciate it.